# Jenkinsfile: How do I rebuild the previous build?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have the ability to detect (programmatically in a `Jenkinsfile`) when the current build has an undefined parameter:

```
properties([
  parameters([
    string(name: 'FOOBAR',
           defaultValue: '',
           description: 'the foo for your bar'),
    ...
  ])
])
...
node('my-host') {
  if (!params.FOOBAR) {
    currentBuild.result = 'ABORTED';
    error("undefined FOOBAR, oh noes");
  }
  // else continue
}
```

Instead of aborting the current and erroring out, how do I rebuild the previous build for this job?

Comment: Trying to understand your wider use case. What if the previous build had a bad parameter? I tend to make the default parameter value be something valid. You might want to take a look at what the pipeline variable currentBuild.getRawBuild() gives you in the Jenkins model to try and obtain the previous build. It will probably need the sandbox turned off or script approvals. Start here http://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/workflow-support/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/support/steps/build/RunWrapper.html

Comment: @macg33zr, that's some good advice. In answer to your question, the job I'm trying to augment catches its parameters from an "upstream" job. This "downstream" knows enough to grab artifacts from upstream --- except when it's triggered by source control changes in _itself_.

Comment: @macg33zr, to address your other question, if the previous build _also_ had a bad parameter, I want infinite recursion into the past until it rebuilds the most recent successful build --- or finally fails if no such build exists.